# Knockout button click event with 2 dialog boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I have a bootstrap modal that contains a form attached to the click event of a knockout button on my page. The form is filled by user and data is sent back to server. I am trying to add a popup prior to the form being displayed that will send data back to server if condition is true and not display the form at all. Just looking for some general idea of basically attaching a first popup before the second.

```
 <button class="btn btn-lg btn-default" data-bind="click: function(){showDialog(true)},
                css: {'btn btn-lg btn-success': hasSelectedFiveCats }, enable: hasSelectedFiveCats">Get Cats</button>
```

Comment: i hope you are looking to show model-pop up conditionally on click function try this http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/762/ . anything i'm missing help me understand .

Comment: basically what i am looking for is a pop up when you first click that button asking if you want to open the modal behind it. Open Modal? Yes no? if no then send default values to server.

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/763/ . hope it helps .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it!

->> [Click to view Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/tk9z32vw/1/)

Here is the general idea!

1. Add code to handle the onSubmit() event for the form
2. In that code block by adding a call to `confirm`, an `OK`, `Cancel` popup message will appear 
   A) If `OK` is pressed, the `confirm` value will equal to `true` 
   B) If `Cancel` is pressed, the `confirm` value will equal to `false`

   C) Wrap the `confirm` with if() statement, and add your logic there.

If you:

1. click ok, the form will submit
2. click No, the form will not submit

CODE:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
    if (confirm("Press a button!") == true) {
       //You pressed OK!"
        //Go ahead 
    } else {
       //You pressed Cancel!
         event.preventDefault();
        $('#msg').text('You pressed Cancel!');
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok! to clarify my answer there!  I intercept the submit event, and I popped up a confirm dialog window. If you click cancel, then I cancel your submit event. If you click "OK", then I do nothing letting the form to submit.